# PHP: Why would 'filetype()' and 'is_file()' fail reading a file on a FTP server?

Tags: php

I'm having a few problems while trying to check files on a FTP server.

I installed a FTP server (filezilla) on a test machine where i could interact with it from another webserver running on the LAN. I used PHP to walk through the directories on the FTP server over the LAN. Within my app i had calls to 'filetype()' and more recently 'is_file()' to check file types etc.

Now i've deployed the app to another place and setup a FTP share on a NAS and run my app on a separate webserver connected to the LAN and here's where the problems start. My app now fails in the 'filetype()' and 'is_file()' calls. I have set the FTP share on the NAS to read/write.

> 'is_file()' = Silent, no error
>   reported.
>
> 'filetype()' = Warning: filetype()
>   [function.filetype]: Lstat failed for
>   `ftp://192.168.0.36/PDFs/6008300/6008386/v1/6008386.pdf`
>   in C:\Program Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\app\app.php
>   on line 326

Any thoughts?

I can work around this error by not using the above functions but that lessens the safety of this script.

EDIT:

PHP is version 5.2.4

The FTP server doesn't require any login username or password.

Comment: Hmmm... how do you disable the automatic ftp link generated in this post?

Comment: do your ftp server need login/password ?

Answer (score 2):

The [is_file()](http://php.net/is_file) and [filetype()](http://php.net/filetype) functions require "stat()" support from the relevant [protocol wrapper](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php).

For FTP/FTPS, [this was lacking in PHP4, but is supported in PHP5](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php).

Have you deployed this on a PHP4 based server?